# Is there a way to revive a coordinator?

Tags: oozie

An oozie coordinator we own has been killed for operational reasons about a week ago. The cluster is now back up and running and ready for business. Can we revive it somehow so it will keep its run history and backfill all missing runs, or do we have to schedule a brand new one?

`oozie job -resume xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-oozie-oozi-C` doesn't error out, but it also doesn't change the status of the coordinator back to RUNNING.

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Unable-to-rerun-oozie-coordinator-once-it-is-killed/m-p/38307#M2090 doesn't give me hope

Answer (score 1):

The command need to rerun an Oozie job is

```
oozie job -change xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-oozie-oozi-C -value status=RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out the killed -> ignored -> running transition? Based on the [docs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.1.2._Coordinator_Job) it should be possible.
It's a two step process: [first one is based -ignore](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Ignore_a_Coordinator_Job), [second one is -change](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Changing_endtimeconcurrencypausetimestatus_of_a_Coordinator_Job).

I've never tried to do this though :)